# Set input format of date in Angular2+

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, date

I have a date I'd like to display using the angular date pipe like so:

```html
<span>{{record.createdDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'}}</span>
```

However, I am being provided the record from a corresponding REST service, with the createdDate being in the form of `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` while angular infers the date to be in `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` So, for example, the 8th of October, 2019, is being displayed as 2019-08-10.

Is there a way I can specify the input type of the date? If not, what is the best way to approach this (updating the service is not possible) ?

Answer (score 0):

Use moment to parse the date

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

const date = moment(yourDateString, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').toDate()
```

Here is a StackBlitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axevss